# Getting error while generating coverage from Gcov and Lcov -'402*', prefer 'A94*'

Tags: android, gcc, code-coverage, android-source, gcov

While running the script with Gcov and lcov it is giving error for**
version '402*', prefer 'A94*'**
I have installed Gcov 9.4.0 and same gcc also

``
lcov --directory . --base-directory . --gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov --capture -o cov.info
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 9.4.0
Using intermediate gcov format
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
Found 1 data files in .
Processing test1.gcda
/home/android/Downloads/Geeta/Test/test1.gcno:version '402*', prefer 'A94*'
geninfo: ERROR: GCOV failed for /home/android/Downloads/Geeta/Test/test1.gcda!

I tried with --gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-9.4.0 also but same error.
``

Anyone know how to resolve this error for gcc and gcov